# Retrieving a key from a dictionary and improving this code

Tags: python

I am setting myself exercises to improve my understanding of Python. I wanted to create a program that calculates vote share for different teams. I started by putting the teams and their corresponding numbers of votes into a dictionary.

I could start by showing the vote share for blue team then red team and so forth, but I feel I would be repeating the same block of code over and over. Can a function be used here instead?

Also is there a way of retrieving a key from a dictionary instead of having to type out "the blue team"?

```
teams = {'blue' : 32224, 'red' : 16885, 'yellow' : 2302, 'green' :     965, 'others' : 482}
total = 52858
team_vote = teams.get('blue')
vote_share = team_vote / total_votes * 100
print(f'the blue team received {team_vote} votes')
print(f'That is a vote share of {vote_share} per cent')
```

Comment: `for key in teams: print (key)` to loop over the keys in a dict.

Comment: you can use ```for key, value in teams.items():  print(f'{key} team received {value} votes')```

Comment: Thanks @Khurshid that has brought me a step closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is as per your need.No need of function for this.

```
teams = {'blue' : 32224, 'red' : 16885, 'yellow' : 2302, 'green' :965, 'others' : 482}
total = 52858
for i in teams.keys():
    team_vote = teams.get(i)
    vote_share = (team_vote / total) * 100
    print('The',i,'team received',teams[i],'votes')
    print('That is a vote share of',vote_share,'per cent')
    print("======")
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your method (yet) but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
teams = {'blue' : 32224, 'red' : 16885, 'yellow' : 2302, 'green' :     965, 'others' : 482}
total = 52858
team_vote = teams.get('blue')
name = {v:k for k,v in teams.items()}.get(team_vote)
vote_share = team_vote / total_votes * 100
print(f'the {name} team received {team_vote} votes')
print(f'That is a vote share of {vote_share} per cent')
```

Answer (score -2):

maybe something like this:

```
for key, value in teams.iteritems():
    if key == 'blue':
        print key
```